# PHP Change array to one dimension

Tags: php, arrays

**Function to generate array format:**

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($rows);
```

**Array generated:**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [TASK_ID] => 2
                [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
                [TASK_LEVEL] => 0
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [TASK_ID] => 9
                                [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
                                [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [TASK_ID] => 10
                                [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
                                [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

[1] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 1
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [TASK_ID] => 4
                            [PARENT_TASKID] => 1
                            [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [TASK_ID] => 5
                            [PARENT_TASKID] => 1
                            [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [TASK_ID] => 6
                                            [PARENT_TASKID] => 5
                                            [TASK_LEVEL] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
    )
```

How can I change the above format into below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 2
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 9
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 10
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
        )

)
```

Tried below code:

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

and

```
$array  = your array

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

But does not seem to work. Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: How are you generating the array? You have to provide us more information to help you. And also what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Pls see the update in question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333085/php-find-the-array-index-key-of-multi-dimensional-array-to-update-array
Try this

Comment: Why downvote ? There has to be a reason for down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a recursive function to flatten the tree as you have used a recursive function to build the tree.

```
function flattenTree($tree)
{
    $flat = array();
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            $children = $item['children'];
            unset($item['children']);
            $flat[] = $item;
            $flat = array_merge($flat, flattenTree($children));
        } else {
            $flat[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $flat;
}

$flat = flattenTree($tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($your_array[0] as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == 'TASK_ID' OR $k == 'PARENT_TASKID') {
        $arr[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Try output:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Hope, it works for you.

Comment: Output -> `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
        )

)`

Comment: Add var_dump of your array so that I can run.

Comment: `var_dump` of expected or existing array ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this for $_FILES parsing when capturing multiple files

```
function multi_array($array)
{
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$elem)
    {
        if(is_array($elem))
        {
            foreach($elem as $x=>$val)
            {
                if(!is_array($val))
                {
                    $new[$x][$key] = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Usage is pretty basic

```
$array = multi_array($array);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: the output is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
function makeOneDimensionArray(array $array, &$res = array())
{
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        $res[] = array(
            'TASK_ID' => $arr['TASK_ID'],
            'PARENT_TASKID' => $arr['PARENT_TASKID']
        );
        if(isset($arr['children']))
        {
            makeOneDimensionArray($arr['children'], $res);
        }

    }

    return $res;

}

$finalArr = makeOneDimensionArray($array);

print_r($finalArr);
```

I hope it help.

Comment: The code is close to what is expected. But I doubt if there are two tasks with `PARENT_TASKID = 0` they will be sorted first and then the child. Pls see the array generated in question.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy : Just put array_merge statement in foreach loop. See my edit.

Comment: The output is same even if its inside foreach. Pls see my question and generated array. It has two records with `PARENT_TASKID = 0`.