# Array where the key should be returned

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$results = array(
  'Always On' => array('alwaysOn', 'microwave'),
  'Laundry' => array('dishWasher', 'washingMachine', 'dryer'),
  'Cooking' => array('oven', 'hob', 'grill', 'kettle'),
  'Refrigeration' => array('refrigeration'),
  'Space Heating' => array('spaceHeating', 'gasBoiler'),
  'Water Heating' => array('waterHeating')
);
```

Now i want to search this for 'hob' and let it return 'Cooking'
How do i do that?

Comment: `foreach` and `in_array`???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in_array function is what you're looking for, this:

```
in_array([1, 2, 3, 4], 2);
```

will return `true` because `2` exists in the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. We can use `in_array` here to check whether one of the child arrays contain the value you are trying to find.

To do so, we have to iterate over each of the arrays in the initial array.

```
foreach($results as $result) {
     ...
}
```

And then check `in_array` against `$result`, to check whether `$result` contains the value of `hob`.

However, once we find the value of `hob`, you want the `key` returning, this can be done by identifying a `key` in the `foreach` definition.

```
foreach($results as $key=>$result) {
    echo $key;
} // will output Always on, Laundry, Cooking, ...
```

So when we iterate over the arrays, once we find the value within an array that we are looking for we are able to return the `$key` value.

As a function

```
function getKeyOfArrayContainingHob($results) {
    foreach($results as $key=>$result)
    {
        if(in_array("hob", $result)) 
        {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as a dynamic function

```
function getKeyOfArrayContainingValue($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$hay)
    {
        if(in_array($needle, $hay)) 
        {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

The `in_array` method is useful here, we can iterate over each key/value pair and then check to see if the value of hob exists within any of those child arrays, in which case return the `$key` of the child array, which we have defined in the foreach (`$key=>$value`).

Comment: This was exactly it :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the kay => value then loop through the value to search for the value you're expecting back, something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$results = array(
  'Always On' => array('alwaysOn', 'microwave'),
  'Laundry' => array('dishWasher', 'washingMachine', 'dryer'),
  'Cooking' => array('oven', 'hob', 'grill', 'kettle'),
  'Refrigeration' => array('refrigeration'),
  'Space Heating' => array('spaceHeating', 'gasBoiler'),
  'Water Heating' => array('waterHeating')
);

function getRowValuesByValue(array $results, $expected) 
{
    foreach ($results as $key => $values) {
        if (in_array($expected, $values)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    throw new \Exception('Value not found');
}


$category = getRowValuesByValue($results, 'hob');

// Cooking
print_r($row);
```

Comment: What, why two loops?

Comment: Question didn't want an array returning, but the key value - though this is useful should that have been the case.

Comment: Oops, I quickly put this together, completely forgot about in_array()

Comment: Again, quickly put it together, mis-read the return requirements, updated my example, thanks for pointing out my mistakes guys!