# Condition goes directly in else even if there is condition which is met in if/esleif block

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-blade, laravel-4.2

I have condition in my blade template which check if customer is paid from api call. The problem is that doesn't matter if some of `if/elseif` conditions is met it's always goes to `else` and show what is in there.

```
@if (is_array($totala['data']['incoming']) || is_object($totala['data']['incoming']))

    @foreach($totala['data']['incoming'] as $key => $date)
    @endforeach
           @if(strpos($date['address'], $address['address']) !== false )

                @if($order['price'] == $date['amount'] )
                    <span>Paid</span>

                @elseif($order['price'] < $date['amount'] )
                    <span>Over Paid</span>


                @elseif($order['price'] > $date['amount'] )
                    <span>Under Paid</span>
                @else                       
                @endif
           @else
                <span>Else block</span>                                
           @endif       
@else
    <span>Unpaid</span>
@endif
```

I've made it like this because if I put inner if/else block inside foreach I've got even unwanted results on the page because they are multiple elements inside `$totala['data']['vouts']` and foreach loop iterate until there is no more elements..

So why the result always goes in else block?

Note: All data is there and is correct. I've triple checked the data in the json array.

Update: Here is example of the array

```
Array
(
  [status] => success
  [data] => Array
    (
        [id] => id
        [incoming] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => address1
                        [amount] => sum1

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => address2
                        [amount] => sum2

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => address3
                        [amount] => sum3

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => address4
                        [amount] => sum4

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => address5
                        [amount] => sum5

                    )
            )
    )
 )
```

With `foreach` I'm looping in array[data][incoming] to search for the address `strpos($date['address'], $address['address']) !== false` then when the address is found I want to go trough conditions.

I just realized that I's always goes in else block because they are multiple arrays in [incoming] and there always conditions are not met. Is that correct? If is that how can I fix it?

Comment: What data is in `$totala['data']['incoming']`? Your code is evaluating based on the final element in this array which might be what you want but using a `foreach` loop isn't the best way to get it. Also - which else block is always being triggered? There's 3 in your example.

Comment: `<span>Else block</span>` this block is always triggered. I've updated my question with example how the array looks.

Comment: Ok so `strpos($date['address'], $address['address'])` is evaluating to false  - what is the value of `$address['address']` in your script?

Comment: it's value which is came from database. It's address saved in database. This address match one of the array inside `[incoming]`. Will always match 1 address inside the `[incoming]`. I mean it should match and if not match should go in else block.

Comment: When I var_dump `$address['address']` and `$date['address']` i see them matching i.e. equals.

Comment: If you are checking for two identical strings why don't you use `if($date['address'] == $address['address'])`? also if there are spaces or any slight formatting differences, the strings won't match, even if they look the same when dumped.

Comment: Because I need to loop in `[incoming]` to find the address if is there. No? Also I just found that `@if(strpos($date['address'], $address['address']) !== false )` this compare always last address in `[incoming]` addresses array. That's why always show `else` block i.e. no matching. If the address is on last spot of the array it doesn't skip to else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messy, but I think this will achieve what you need.

```
@if (is_array($totala['data']['incoming']) || is_object($totala['data']['incoming']))

   <?php
      // find the first matching address in $totala['data']['incoming']
      $match = false;
      foreach ($totala['data']['incoming'] as $data) {
         if ($data['address'] == $address['address']) {
            $match = $data;
            break;
         }
      }
   ?>

   @if($match !== false )

      @if($order['price'] == $match['amount'] )
         <span>Paid</span>
      @elseif($order['price'] < $match['amount'] )
         <span>Over Paid</span>
      @else
         <span>Under Paid</span>                      
      @endif
   @else
      <span>No match found</span>                                
   @endif
@else
   <span>Unpaid</span>
@endif
```

If you are only interested in the matching data you should extract this information in your controller - not in the view.

**Update:**
If using PHP >= 5.5.0 you have access to the array column function, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785508/2180572 for an explanation and example. In your code replace the php block with...

```
<?php
   $match = array_search($address['address'], array_column($totala['data']['incoming'], 'address'));
   if($match) {
      $match = $totala['data']['incoming'][$match];
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to extract it in my controller and didn't succeeded.. that's why I wen in the view. Can you give me example how to extract it in the controller and share the result? Will test this answer in a sec.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help!