# How to search for the index of a string in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, indexing

I need to find the of index a string in the following array after it has been exploded. So in the example I'd need to find the index for "really". How can I do this?

```
function explode2D($row_delim, $col_delim, $str) {
        return array_map(function ($line) use ($col_delim) {
            return explode($col_delim, $line);
        }, explode($row_delim, $str));
    } // - slick coding by trincot


$string = 'red<~>blue<~>orange[|]yellow<~>purple<~>green[|]really<~>dark<~>brown';

$array = explode2D("[|]", "<~>", $string);
```

this returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [1] => blue
            [2] => orange
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => yellow
            [1] => purple
            [2] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => really
            [1] => dark
            [2] => brown
        )

)
```

so i tried this

```
$search = 'really';

$index = array_search($search, $array);

print($index);
```

nothing :(

Comment: See [PHP Multidimensional Array Searching (Find key by specific value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search` won't work because you're looking for a string in an array of *arrays*. You need to loop over the outer array and `array_search` each set inside that array.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $set) {
    $index = array_search($search, $set);
    if (false !== $index) {
        echo "Found '$search' at index $index of set $key";
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which index you're looking for, because with a structure like this, there are two indexes that indicate where your search string is, one for the outer array and one for the inner array. But if you break the loop after `$search` is found, then `$key` will be the correct index of the outer array at that point, so you'll have both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if (($key = array_search($search, $array[$i])) !== false) {
        var_dump(array($i, $key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$search = 'really';

$index = -1;
$location = [];

foreach($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($array[$i]); $j++){
        if($search == $array[$i][$j]){
            $location = [$i, $j];
            $index++;
            break;
        } else {
            $index++;
        }
    } 
}

print_r($location); // This gives you the position where the match is found i.e. [2, 0];
echo $index; // This is the direct index of the search result i.e. 6

print($index);
```

This should work. Didn't get to try it, but it should...