# Search array by value in key and get another key's value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

here is my array:

```
[0] => Array
  (
      [messages] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [message] => This is for sandwich
                  )
              [1] => Array
                  (
                      [message] => This message is for burger
                  )

          )
      [price] => Array
          (
              [amount] => 5
              [currency] => USD
          )

[1] => Array
  (
      [messages] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [message] => This is a message for a delicious hotdog
                  )

          )
      [price] => Array
          (
              [amount] => 3
              [currency] => USD
          )
  )
```

i want to search in ALL arrays and I want to search for the word "burger". I want to get the price and amount of "burger" which is 5. If I search for the word "hotdog", it will return the price amount 3. How can i do that? thanks

Comment: Please also show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Use a similar solution, replace the exact value match with a `pregmatch`  or `strpos` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value

Comment: @GayanL can you show example please? thanks

Comment: @JohnJaoill I think every question has its own importance and value, but here you should make a try first then post for help with the code you have tried.

Comment: @JohnJaoill the accepted answer in the above comment , `$product[$field] === $value` this step needs to change `strpos('burger', $product[$field]) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop and then use `strpos` or `stripos`.

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row['messages'] as $row2) {
        if(strpos($row2['message'], 'burger') !== false) {
            $stringFound = true;
        } else {
            $stringFound = false;
        }
    }
    if($stringFound === true) {
        $price = $row['price']['amount'];
    } else {
        $price = '0';
    }
}
echo $price;
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$array` be your array. I Think It may Work.

```
<?php
    $check = 'hotdog';

    foreach($array as $products){
        foreach($products['messages'] as $messages){
         if (strpos($messages['message'], $check) !== false) {
            echo $check.' Found. Price'. $products['price']['amount'] .'</br>' ;
         }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we are using `array_column`, `implode` and `preg_match`.

> **1.** [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for retrieving specific column of an array
>
> **2.** [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) joins a array with a glue to make it string.
>
> **3.** [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) here for matching specific word in the given string.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/806106)

```
$toSearch="hotdog";

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(preg_match("/\b$toSearch\b/",implode(",",array_column($value["messages"],"message"))))
    {
        echo $value["price"]["amount"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Because you are searching for the first qualifying price only, it is best practice to use a conditional `break` to short circuit the loops.  There is no reason to do more cycles if you have found a qualifying entry.
2. Instantiate the `$amount` variable with a `null` value before the loop to properly distinguish between a successful search and an unsuccessful one.
3. `str_contain()` is the modern function to case-sensitively search for a substring (PHP7.4 and higher).  If you need case-insensitivity, you will need to use `stripos($message['message'], $needle) !== false`.  If you need to match whole words, you will need to call `preg_match("/\b$needle\b/i", $message['message'])`.  If using regex and the `$needle` is coming from user input, you will need to apply escaping beforehand with `$needle = preg_quote($needle, '/');`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Sr4rm))

```
$needle = 'burger';

$amount = null;
foreach ($haystack as ['messages' => $messages, 'price' => $price]) {
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        if (str_contains($message['message'], $needle)) {
            $amount = $price['amount'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_export($amount);
// 5
```