# Access object in array

Tags: arrays, object

I need to get to the [slug] => coaching... However the array number changes and I need to access whatever the number is? I know I can use categories->terms[10]->slug for this one, but how do I access whatever the number?

```
[categories] => EM_Categories Object
    (
        [is_ms_global:protected] => 1
        [taxonomy:protected] => event-categories
        [meta_key:protected] => event-category
        [terms_name:protected] => categories
        [term_class:protected] => EM_Category
        [terms] => Array
            (
                [10] => EM_Category Object
                    (
                        [option_ms_global] => 1
                        [option_name] => category
                        [taxonomy] => event-categories
                        [id] => 10
                        [term_id] => 10
                        [name] => Coaching
                        [slug] => coaching
                        [term_group] => 0
                        [term_taxonomy_id] => 10
                        [description] => 
                        [parent] => 0
                        [count] => 2
                        [image_url] => 
                        [color] =>
```

Comment: Please tag the question with an appropriate programming language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array

Comment: PHP: [PHP Multidimensional Array Searching (Find key by specific value)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335142/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which your language is, but in JS you can use `find` fn with a lambda expression.

In your example

```
TermsArray.find((x)=> x[slug] == "coaching");
```

Or something like that.