# Get key from array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, key

So i need to return the number (6, 8 or 10) with the country value.
 So in the example, with 'sweden' its supposed to return 8 but the key of the array is apparently just Array(). Is the wrong  in the structure of my array or the usage of `array_keys`?

```
$list= array (
  'list' => 
  array (
    6 => 
    array (
        'default',
        'finland'
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
        'sweden',
        'norway'
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
        'germany',
        'belgia'
    ),
  ),
);
print_r(array_keys($list, "sweden"));
```

return: `Array()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multidimensional Array Searching (Find key by specific value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value)

Comment: doesnt look to be

Comment: What? use the accepted Answer that is working ;) `arrray_keys` isn't working with multidimensional arrays very well.

Comment: in that question its  an associative array and is looking for 'slug' with slugs value, this is different

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

First, the array you want to search is `$list['list']`, not `$list` itself.

Second, the second argument to `array_keys()` is only useful for 1-dimensional arrays. You have a 2-dimensional array, but `array_keys()` will not automatically search inside the nested arrays. So you need to write your own loop or use `array_filter()`.

```
$results = array();
foreach ($list['list'] as $key => $value) {
    if (array_search('sweden', $value) !== false) {
        $results[] = $key;
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

Comment: im getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' , do i need to edit something?

Comment: Should be `foreach`, not `for`

Answer (score 0):

use foreach for it.

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
foreach($list as $key => $value ){  
        $arr = array_keys($value);//this has your (6, 8 or 10)         
        foreach($arr as $val){
             print_r($value[$val]);//showing array data of 6,8,10 indexes
        }  
    }
```

output:
[image]