# Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Tags: php

I'm getting this notice:

> Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference

```
private function &getPageByLabel(&$pages, $label){
    foreach($pages as &$page){
        if($page['label'] == $label) return $page;
    }
    return false; //THIS IS THE LINE THAT THE ERROR MESSAGE MENTIONS
}
```

I'm using ZF 1.12 and PHP 5.5.9

Comment: `&$page` is wrong because the index can't be used as acumulator, should be `$pages` instead

Comment: I have never seen a function reference like this. `&getPageByLabel` looks wrong to me

Comment: @aynber That it's true, `&getPageByLabel` is wrong and need to be removed the & symbol

Comment: Please check my answer as I've updated it since first posting with more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multidimensional Array Searching (Find key by specific value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value)

Answer (score 0):

Your function specifies that it returns a reference to a variable (meaning it does not copy the value, it passes exactly the version that you have inside the function).

Since you return a constant, there is no variable associated with this, so it *should* not work. PHP is kind though, and interprets what you meant to write as:

```
private function &getPageByLabel(&$pages, $label){
    foreach($pages as &$page){
        if($page['label'] == $label) return $page;
    }
    $return_value = false;
    return $return_value;
}
```

Removing the `&` before `getPageByLabel` will remove the error, since now you will be returning a (copied) value instead of a reference.

Though note that this may cause your code to malfunction, since you were expecting a reference to one of your `$pages`, likely to modify it externally. Without the reference, you will just modify the copy externally and the `$page` in `$pages` will remain unchanged.

A better way is probably to create a 'dummy object' to return.

You could make a 'dummy page' named `$no_page` and return that instead of `false`. Then externally you should be able to determine whether or not the page exists by:

```
$page = $x->getPageByLabel(...); 
if ($page === $x->no_page) {
    // no page found!
}
```

A cleaner option is to check for existence first though it is slightly slower:

```
private function pageExistsWithlabel(&$pages, $label) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page['label'] == $label) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private function &getPageByLabel(&$pages, $label){
    foreach($pages as &$page){
        if($page['label'] == $label) return $page;
    }
    // throw an error here
}

if (! $x->pageExistsWithlabel(...)) {
    // handle the case where the page does not exist to prevent the error
} else {
    $page = $x->getPageByLabel(...);
}
```