# array_walk callback not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have PeopleSearch class that has all static method instead of one method. Whne i call this function then i receive exceptio that is below

```
array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'setUserRequestStatus' not found or invalid function name
```

Below is my working code

```
class PeopleSearch {

        public static function searchPeople($client = null) {
             $inputs = Request::get('data');
             $data['User'] = [];
             $result = $client->search(self::prepare_search_params_people($inputs));
             if (!empty($result) && count($result['hits']['hits']) > 0) {
                  $userArray = array_column($result['hits']['hits'], '_source');
                  // check user friend requests
                  $requestSents = FriendRequest::get_friend_requests($inputs['User']['id'], array_column(array_column($result['hits']['hits'], '_source'), 'id'))->toArray();
                 array_walk($userArray,'setUserRequestStatus',array_column($requestSents, 'request_to'));
                 echo "<pre>";
                 print_r($userArray);
                 exit;
             }
       }

      public function setUserRequestStatus($user, $key, $requests_sent_to) {
            $user['request_sent'] = in_array($user['id'], $requests_sent_to) ? true : false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Change `'setUserRequestStatus'` with `[$this, 'setUserRequestStatus']`

Comment: @splash58 thanks for help but after implementing your answer i get this error "Undefined variable: this"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375501/476

Comment: ^ https://eval.in/909064 I missed that method is static

Comment: @splash58 thank you so much to help problem is solved  through your provided link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the manual please replace your code with the below one

array_walk($userArray, array('self', 'setUserRequestStatus'));

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks to answer but after implementing your answer i get this error "Undefined variable: this"

Comment: Your callback function is static so you may use the below code snippet array_walk($array, array('self', 'walkFunction'));

Comment: Please give a up vote if you find the answer is helpful